# U haz Backbone retroactive `on` event listener?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

My goal is to be able to have this code run the alert() even thou the event is triggered after the listener is set up. Standard Backbone.Events.on doesn't support this.

```
app.trigger('alarm');

app.onRetro('alarm', function(){
  alert();
});
```

Retroactive event listeners should fire immediately so long as the event has been already triggered at least once. They should also continue to fire for each subsequent trigger.

Something can be written to handle this by checking app._events.alarm.length, but I'm wondering if someone has already solved this problem.

Comment: you mean like this library? https://github.com/matinm/backbone.heap

Comment: @watson.. sorry my bad

Comment: @jycr753 Im not sure that library adds anything beyond the app._events object which we already have.

Comment: Would you describe a more specific use case than this general one which is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Would you want the retroactive events to fire immediately after the first listener is wired up, of does in need to allow for an arbitrary number of listeners to be wired up before triggering the retroactive events?

Comment: @BillyChan What do you not understand, if I might inquire?

Comment: @bejonbee Retroactive event listeners should fire immediately so long as the event has been already triggered at least once. They should also continue to fire for each subsequent trigger.

Comment: What you described is somewhat abstract to me, and there is no such method onRetro exists. Could you use a real world example to describe the exact effect you need?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cL6TW/2/) that will help you achieve what you want.

In this example if you call :

```
Backbone.Events.trigger('alarm', { retro: true });
```

an `alarm` event will be waiting the next call to

```
Backbone.Events.on('alarm', callback)
```

to execute the callback.

I don't know what's your need. So I set a retro event to be removed once it's used. You can modify it to your needs.

Comment: what do you mean by `retroactive` ? In your question you said that the code you have provided is not supported by `Backbone.Events.on`, am I right ?

Comment: Yes I said that, and retroactive: adj. 1. made effective as of a date prior to enactment -- so i want to trigger an event, then add a listener and have it run because the event has been triggered already.